# Identifying and finding replacement for LCD display module

Tags: identification, display, repair

I have a [Line 6 POD X3](http://line6.com/legacy/podx3) amp modeler. It has a small LCD display module which was shattered during my last move and the device became unusable.

I have attempted to identify the model of this display to try and find a replacement. I have opened the casing, disconnected the module and found the model number on it.

Full info as appears on the display:

Sticker:
`CGM12864CFAA`, `KS070705E002403`

On plastic itself:
`CGM12864 C-A`, `VER: 3.0`

However when I search for it, I can't find this specific module. So what is the way to precisely identify this display module? Do I have enough information here?

Front:
[image]

Back (it seems that the chips are sealed). At the bottom, following text appears: *MADE IN CASIL, CGM12864 C-A, VER: 3.0*
[image]

These schematics were found [here](http://elektrotanya.com/line-6_pod_x3.pdf/download.html) (Thanks to @Passerby). However I am not experienced enough to realize what replacement LCD can be used here given this information:
[image]

Comment: This site is not for "where can I buy this part" type of questions. 

The 12864 number suggests that this a 128 x 64 pixel monochrome graphics LCD. You might be able to see a controller chip on back side, probably a KS type. With that controller type, the 128x64 size, and the phyiscal dimensions you might be able to find a replacement part. Maybe try crystalfontz.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen Hi and thank you for your comments. Actually I might rephrase my question. What I am really interested in is how to correctly recognize this screen in order to find a replacement. I will edit my question and hopefully it will fit better into this site's scope.

Comment: Provide at least pictures of the back and front.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I have added a front picture. I will add back picture later today. Thanks.

Comment: The picture of the back should have sufficient resolution to read any markings on the print and chips.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen That's my problem. The only thing stated there is the model(?) as I have mentioned in my question. However I couldn't find such component while looking for it on the nets. So I wonder how can I figure out an acceptable alternative.

Comment: KS0707 refers to a HD61202-code-compatible graphic display ic (Like how most character lcds are based on hd44780-compatible controllers). A single ic normally covers a 64x64 block, so there should be two ics like it. Furthermore, it's also a 20 pin lcd, which is the standard count for this type. What this means is that most of the time, **you can replace the lcd with a different one, as long as the controllers are based on the same code** This would involve some backwards engineering, but nothing too hard.

Comment: @Passerby Thanks you for your comments. Could you provide any directions to how it's done? Maybe any online tutorials? Thanks.

Comment: @EugeneS found the service manual. Boy do people get lucky when I have insomnia. http://elektrotanya.com/line-6_pod_x3.pdf/download.html  Page 6 has the "preliminary pinout" with standard names for the pins. The module is custom made for them, but that could mean pcb size/shape, bezel/screen/display/backlight color, or possibly some custom firmware but I doubt that much. You are also lucky it mention ks0707, the service manual did not have that. You can get any electronically working with them with some wires switched around, but fitting it in the case is a different problem.

Comment: @Passerby Thanks a lot! This information is very helpful. Can you please elaborate what `kso0707` means and why am I so lucky to mention it? :) So basically you say that I can try and fit other 128x64 lcd screens? I don't really have much experience reading this type of schematics so how would I match these pins on this chart to a different module, say this one: http://www.digikey.com.au/product-detail/en/NHD-12864AZ-FL-YBW/NHD-12864AZ-FL-YBW-ND/1701274

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize what I found.

CGM12864 refers to a 128x64 Graphic LCD.

KS070705E002403 is a reference to the Samsung KS0707 lcd controller, often paired with the KS0708. These are similar to their KS0107/8 lcd controllers. These are code compatible with standard HD61202 graphic lcd controllers, so most can be swapped in with only wiring changes. These type of generic graphic lcds are a dime a dozen and easily found, with variations on colors, backlight types, physical sizes, and pinouts. Some have onboard negative power circuits, but this one does not.

The picture provided by OP shows 3 chip on board (COB) blobs. These normally correlate to 1 KS0707 and 2 KS0708 lcd controllers, for a 128x64 display. Very standard. Each KS0708 handles a 64 x 64 block of the display. These displays can also be found in 64x64, or 128x128, or 256x64 variations, with a different amount of lcd controllers and pinouts to handle the chip selects.

[This pdf](http://www.telcona.com/fileadmin/user_upload/products/Casil/Telcona-CGM12864.pdf) is a basic datasheet for Casil Semiconductor CGM12864, very basic, standard 20 pin graphic lcd, just confirms the same pinout as the Podx3's lcd.

[The service manual with pinout and schematics is here](http://elektrotanya.com/line-6_pod_x3.pdf/download.html) (must be downloaded).

The manual lists the LCD as:
`PCBA DISPLAY LCD 128x64 Pos Graphic 6-:00 Amber P10-1` and `LCD CUSTOM FOR FBV FAMILY TQL001TPL-V3 (VERSION 3)`

The first line confirms the Size (128x64 pixels), Positive display, Graphic Display, 6-:00 refers to viewing angle (6 Degrees), Amber refers to the screen color.

**The module is custom made for them**, but that could mean pcb size/shape (most likely), bezel/screen/display/backlight color, backlight type, or possibly some custom firmware. **It is unknown which, so you can never be 100% sure a generic replacement will work 100%**. You will not find the same exact lcd module, as custom designs are a rarely mass produced and are confidential.

The pinout is very standard names for a graphic LCD of this type. CSA and CSB are the chip selects, they switch between the two column drivers (Could be CS1/CS2 or Sel1/2 etc). VSS is ground. VDD is +5v, power for the lcd logic. VLCD is a negative power supply line for the LCD display. RS is another name for D/I, switches between data and instruction commands. R/W switches between read and write modes. If tied to ground, this means the display is in write only mode (normal). E is the enable line, when toggled, data on the data pins will be read into memory. DB0-DB7 are the 8 data lines. LED(A) is the LED anode pin, positive 4.2~5V. LED(K) is the LED cathode pin, tied to ground. Vout is unused (could be named VEE). /RESET is the reset line for the lcd.

The schematic shows that the VDD 5v positive supply, the VLCD negative supply, and the LED supply are all on board the Podx3, not the lcd module, so that saves any trouble in recreating them.

**To replace with a generic character lcd**, you need to make sure the lcd is ks0107/8, ks0707/8, or hd61202 compatible. You will need to rewire the cable from the main board to the lcd module to match the existing pin out by name or find one with the same pin out. You will want one with a LED backlight to match the original, but backlight color and display color arn't important (there are some nice blue ones). And for the most part, you will need to figure out how to mount or fit it in the case, if you cannot find one with the same lcd or board Physical size.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! It is VERY helpful and will give me a much better understanding of what I'm after. Thanks!